# How to add data-stripe attribute to text_field_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

In the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms), the example form shows the following input

```
<input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
```

I'm using the following code in ruby (rails 4) to generate my input

```
<%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, :placeholder => "Card Number" %>
```

which generates

```
<input id="card_number" placeholder="Card Number" type="text" />
```

However, I'm unable to add the data-stripe attribute. I guess I could always add the field manually and not use rails feature. However, it'll be tedious to replace other functions such as `select_year` and `select_month`. So, how can I add a custom attribute when generating an input using rails? Specifically, `data-stripe="number"`

Comment: have you tried `"data-stripe" => 123` in the options?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```rb
<%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, placeholder: "Card Number", data: { stripe: 'number' } %>
```

What I think you’re after.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you! (I'll accept it after 10 minute limit)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed!

Just FYI to future readers: make sure to add that comma after `"Card Number"`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, :placeholder => "Card Number", "data-stripe" => 123 %>
```